# Link HTML page to chtml page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want a method to connect a button in an HTML page to chtml page in ASP MVC project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elzyi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the basic form `<a href="index.chtml"><button>mypage</button></a>` inside your html file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href='@Url.Content("~/staticFiles/testing.html")'>Footer 2</a></li>
```

@Url.Content() is used to map the url to a file on your web application.

Hope this answer will be helpful to you.